# Sql update statement, any way of knowing what it actually did?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

Typically, I test an update by running a query using the where statement and then after verifying that it does what I think I want it to copying the where clause to the update statement and executing it. But is there any way of getting the statement to return what the update did besides the '4 rows updated'

Comment: What SQL server are you using? This would require a very implementation specific solution.

Comment: What database server do you use? Which technology do oyu use to access it?

Comment: can you show the example of your code ? do you want the solution to be on pure sql ? (what other languages do you use)

Comment: Sorry it was a vague question, but was looking for any and all answers :) The output clause of T-SQL looks intriguing so far!

Comment: @mellerbeck - Assuming you have tagged correctly you won't be able to use it and will have to remain intrigued!

Comment: @martin hopefully we will upgrade someday! I'm just glad that it looks like it was addressed since it seems like a very useful clause!

Answer (score 1):

Sure, take a look at the output clause of T-SQL
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

Comment: Doesn't exist in SQL Server 2000

Comment: Did you just add that tag? Could have sworn it wasn't there a moment ago! :D

Comment: sorry, yes I need to get use to tagging

Answer (score 0):

You could load your records into a temp table/variable in SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE(ID INT)

INSERT INTO @Temp (ID) 
SELECT ID    
FROM Customer
WHERE AcctBalance > 5000

--inspect as needed

UPDATE Customer
SET AcctBalance = 0
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM @Temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

That depend in the server, library that you use, in php, [pdo exec](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php) return number of row effected by delete or update cluase